# String split in javascript after each second comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I am having this string:

```
16First,Second,18Third,Fourth,25Fifth,Sixth,38Seven,Eight
```

I want to split the string in a way that it will produce and array containing each element after the second comma, basically

```
16First,Second,(split here)18Third,Fourth,(split here)25Fifth,Sixth,(split here)38Seven,Eight
```

So the final output would be an array like this:

```
Array[1] = 16First,Second,
Array[2] = 18Third,Fourth,
Array[3] = 25Fifth,Sixth,
Array[4] = 38Seven,Eight
```

And so on no matter how long the string is. I am confused because it needs to split on each 2nd comma and there isn't ( or at least I haven't find any guide/solution about it ).

Comment: There's no easy way (that I know of) to do this in one step. You'd have to split the string on a comma, then create a new list from the resulting list you get from the original split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regex match all approach here with the help of `match()`:

```js
var input = "16First,Second,18Third,Fourth,25Fifth,Sixth,38Seven,Eight";
var matches = input.match(/[^,]+,[^,]+/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: That was easier than I though. Indeed a working answer.